# Is the practice of passing parent object as reference for parent object interaction Evil?

Tags: c#

In some code reviews of legacy c# code i've been doing recently I've seen a number of examples like this:

```
class ManagerParentClass
{
    public string CustomProperty{get;set;}
    public void Log(string message);

    void DoABunchOfTasks()
    {
       new SomethingService().DoSomething(this);
    }
}
```

with the following:

```
public class SomethingService
{
    ManagerParentClass _manager;

    void DoSomething(ManagerParentClass manager)
    {
        _manager = manager;

        // do something
        _manager.CustomProperty = "hello world";
        _manager.Log("said hello world");
    }
}
```

While this works fine on the surface, I'm concerned that this is a bit of an anti-pattern that may cause evil things with garbage collection.

Will this break the generational garbage collector in .Net's ability to clean the parent and child objects up properly or anything else negative?

Comment: The GC won't keep a root if they are'nt being used. This is just bad programming I think. The classes have intermixed responsibilities. Fantastic question though.

Comment: Parent-child references are common in any decently involved object graph.  That is the blessing of the .NET GC.  We used to have to use `CopyMemory` and `ObjPtr` to break the circular references in the unforgiving memory management system back in VB6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh yes, this is a terrible anti-pattern in general. I work with a code base that uses this a lot and it is sheer madness.

The biggest offense? Violation of encapsulation and the tight coupling between the classes that comes with it: `SomethingService` knows too much about `ManagerParentClass`, and `ManagerParentClass` gives up control of itself to `SomethingService`.

Two better alternatives:

1. Make `DoSomething()` an instance method of `ManagerParentClass`, this is in closer keeping with an essential point of object orientation: data structures carry their operators
2. Make `SomethingService` a *pure* method that does some calculation and returns a value, the caller may then make the assignment to the `ManagerParentClass`

Of course, both of these refactorings involve an end-game mutation of `ManagerParentClass`, and coming from a functional programming angle, I would try to avoid that altogether. But without more information, I can't recommend a course for that.

Comment: I disagree. It's almost necessary to do this kind of thing when you are using the visitor pattern to implement what amounts to a programming language where you're creating functions that operate on a set of data that's contained in an external cache or storage. Maybe "in general" it's a bad idea but there are absolutely some circumstances where it appears as though it's absolutely necessary to do this kind of thing. Try implementing a virtual CPU with instructions, external storage and validating that the external storage is legit without doing this. It's really hard.

Comment: @MikeTaber yes, I agree that appropriate application of the visitor pattern is a legitimate case where you would want to do this kind of thing. However note that some languages like F# have features (e.g. discriminant unions and pattern matching) that supplant the visitor pattern. i.e. the legitimate need to do this may just reflect a missing language feature.

Comment: Perhaps that's true. But this question is about C#, not F#, and whether or not the practice of passing a parent reference to the child is inherently evil. I think the answer is much more contextual and given the above example, it's hard to say. I think it's poor design given this specific example but there are sometimes good reasons for doing this. That was my only point. One place that this will absolutely cause problems is in serialization because the parent references are invalidated when the object is serialized. You can take it into account, but it gets ugly. However it works... soo... :)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a decent way of de-coupling classes from each other - what you've written looks a lot like the visitor pattern.

Your example as written doesn't have much of a memory impact at all, because SomethingService doesn't hold onto ManagerParentClass except for the length of that method. If we were to assume instead that SomethingService would save such an instance during construction or regular methods, then it's slightly more complicated.

Having SomethingService hold a reference to ManagerParentClass means that ManagerParentClass is going to be held in reference 1) as long as SomethingService is held in memory through some chain of references that lead back to a GC root and 2) as long as SomethingService maintains its reference to MPC.

If SS were to release its reference (null it out), then problem solved. If SS were itself to no longer be referenced by anything, then the GC will know that SS can be GCd, and if MPC is then only held by SS, then MPC can be in turn GCd.

Comment: -1 `ManagerParentClass` and `SomethingService` are clearly tightly coupled with this approach. If it were in fact the visitor pattern, then that is tight coupling with a purpose (OO-language making up for lack of discriminant unions), but I am not convinced it is (and looking like the visitor pattern but not quite sounds frightful indeed).

Comment: I don't think it is visitor at all, but the rest of the answer is fine.